# Get Session from Google Script Blank

Tags: google-apps-script

I developed a google script that can get user's email by session every time someone views a specific spreadsheet. However, recently I am getting a few blank email addresses with the timestamp is available. Here is the output in the google sheet:

[image: Screenshot-Google-Sheet]

And here is the google script:

```js
function onOpen() {
   var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
   scriptProperties.setProperty((Session.getActiveUser().getEmail() == '' ? Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail() : Session.getActiveUser().getEmail())+"_"+randomString(20, "aA0"),Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+7", "M-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss"));
}
```

What could possibly cause this? Is there any solution? Please kindly help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getEmail()` function may return `null` in some cases, described in [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/user.html#getEmail()):

> The circumstances in which the email address is available vary: for example, the user's email address is not available in any context that allows a script to run without that user's authorization, like a simple onOpen(e) or onEdit(e) trigger, a custom function in Google Sheets, or a web app deployed to "execute as me" (that is, authorized by the developer instead of the user). However, these restrictions generally do not apply if the developer runs the script themselves or belongs to the same G Suite domain as the user.

In case it does, the ternary expression you use in your code:

```js
Session.getActiveUser().getEmail() == '' ? Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail() : Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()
```

Will evaluate the "falsy" statement (the one after the colon), namely `Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()`, since `null != ''`.

In order to get better results, I suggest you modify your ternary expression as follows (notice the changes in the condition used):

```js
Session.getActiveUser().getEmail() ? Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail() : Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()
```

Now, when `getEmail()` returns `false`, the effective user's email will be the one returned by your expression.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Btw, is there any other alternative methods to record an email address of spreadsheet viewers?

Comment: Hello @HafizHanifi, sadly, there is no other way of reliably obtaining the user's e-mail address. This is due to Google's strict privacy & security policies. In case it imperative for you to obtain the user's e-mail, you can consider using [`prompt()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui#promptprompt) to display a dialog where the user may input it.